# AWS Lambda - Slow bandwidth? (Lambdas + Scraper - Puppeteer)

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, networking, aws-lambda, puppeteer

have a quick question.
I am maximizing the amount of Lambda most of the time and running puppeteer on them.
At some point, the Lambda bandwidth becomes slower and puppeteer gets a major slowdown.
Is it possible that all of my lambdas are running in the same network?

I am running all of them in a private VPC + Elastic IP.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that all of my lambdas are running in the same network?

You answered it yourself with this:

> I am running all of them in a private VPC + Elastic IP.

Yes, in this case, all the traffic from the Lambda will go through the same VPC (same network). This is accomplished by placing an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) inside the VPC, which essentially creates a tunnel between the Lambda and your VPC. This ENI is shared between concurrent executions as well, so probably this may also cause slow-downs for the number of concurrent executions is high.